# Event triggers don't work

Tags: .net, silverlight, events, triggers, windows-phone-7

I have some trigger in my Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app such as

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Height="100">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:10" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

But when Loaded event fires, XamlParseException occurs.
I googled a bit, but found nothing.

Any idea to find solution? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed your code a bit:

- Changed the RoutedEvent to Grid.Loaded
- Added the TargetName with a reference to the Grid
- Change the TargetProperty to Grid.Opacity

view the code below:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Height="100">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"  Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Opacity">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTim>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:10" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```